# How can I tell InstallShield about assembly dependencies which are not referenced but used by dependency injection with unity?

Tags: dependency-injection, windows-installer, unity-container, installshield

My MSI setup built by InstallShield 2011 (Stand alone version on a TFS) does not include all the required assemblies. The assemblies are not directly referenced in the project but injected dynamically by dependency injection with Unity.

It looks like InstallShield does not recognize the required assemblies, can't resolve the dependencies. Using Reflector shows quite the same sparse result for the dependencies.

So my question is: How can I tell InstallShield about these not referenced but required assemblies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest just adding the assemblies to your InstallShield project. Project Output Groups and Dependency Scans at Build are both fragile; they can cause unexpected and unwarned changes to your installer that break minor upgrade rules. It's still probably useful to leave the Properties scan in place, however.

Comment: So adding dependencies manually is more robust? Quite some work to... I hope, once done this effort, TFS should be able to build a working installer automatically.

Comment: Well, for the external dlls your solution works very well. For the own project based ons this doesn't work on the TFS. I had to include a "dependency anchor". This is a simple internal class just using all modules once directly and without dependency injection. Now the scan sees the required own dlls.

Comment: Personally using dependency scanning as a some magical easy button is a bad idea in my opinion.  Just author the files into your installer and be done with it.  You know your own code better then InstallShield or any other tool does.

Comment: Going by your suggestion of adding the assemblies into the installshield project, the assemblies and its dependencies will get deployed on the file system of the computer. In my case I just want to use an assembly and its dependencies only during the install process and then get rid of them after the installation is done?

Comment: By the way, when you say adding the assemblies into your installshield project then you mean to add them into Organization -> Components -> AllOtherFiles -> Files. Do you?

Comment: @RBT: This sounds like it should be a new question. That said, look into the Support Files view or ISClrWrap table for the former, per your use case, and qualified yes to the latter. (I would probably use the Files and Folders view to get individual components for each PE file.)

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one implementation assembly you end up shipping, just have the application reference it.  If not, Michael would have the better answer.

Comment: No, it's a quite complex solution with over 25 projects inside. Unfortunately (from the installation developer's point of view) we can't throw away the dynamic dependency injection. Looks like I have to add the dependencies manually.

Comment: Lars, no I wasn't saying throw away the DI.  I simply was trying to say if you have say IEmailService, and there's only ever one implemention of EmailService, just reference the assembly containing the EmailService implementation.  But if you have two, and only one is put in place by your installer, then you don't really have any other choice but to work it out yourself.